# Passing ruby variable to provisioner

Tags: vagrant, provisioning

I have a Vagrant file that defines a provisioner like this:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "set_rmi_hostname.sh", :args => "<ip_address> <target>"
```

ip_address and target  are ruby variables defined in the same file:

```
ip = Socket.ip_address_list.detect{|intf| intf.ipv4_private?}
ip_address = ip.ip_address if ip
target = "my_target"
```

How can I expand these two variables and pass them to my script?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `#{variable}` to use string expansion in Ruby:

`config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "set_rmi_hostname.sh", :args => "#{ip_address} #{target}"`