# Print message after booting vagrant machine with "vagrant up"

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I need to display a message on the completion of the `vagrant up` command.

I've tried defining a function:

```
def hello
    puts 'hello'
end
```

And then calling it and the end of the file:

```
hello
```

But it always prints at the *beginning* of the output rather than the end. How can I print a message at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once I've started to learn Ruby I've found the ideal solution :)

**BEGIN** Declares code to be called before the program is run.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "This is main Ruby Program"
BEGIN {
    puts "Initializing Ruby Program"
}
```

it will produce this:

```
Initializing Ruby Program
This is main Ruby Program
```

And it works perfectly inside of Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 27):

Vagrant now has builtin support for a message to appear after `vagrant up`. Just add this to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.post_up_message = "This is the start up message!"
```

And then after your VM has come up you'll see this message in green:

```
==> default: Machine 'default' has a post `vagrant up` message. This is a message
==> default: from the creator of the Vagrantfile, and not from Vagrant itself:
==> default:
==> default:     This is the start up message!
```

Answer (score 20):

You can also use a HEREDOC style variable with the `config.vm.post_up_message` like so:

```
$msg = <<MSG
------------------------------------------------------
Local Websphere, accessible at 127.0.0.1

URLS:
 - app under test  - http://localhost:8080/<app url>/
 - ibm console     - http://localhost:9060/ibm/console

------------------------------------------------------
MSG

...
...

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.post_up_message = $msg
end
```

Which will result in output like so:

```
==> default: Machine 'default' has a post `vagrant up` message. This is a message
==> default: from the creator of the Vagrantfile, and not from Vagrant itself:
==> default:
==> default: ------------------------------------------------------
==> default: Local Websphere, accessible at 127.0.0.1
==> default:
==> default: URLS:
==> default:  - app under test  - http://localhost:8080/<app url>/
==> default:  - ibm console     - http://localhost:9060/ibm/console
==> default:
==> default: ------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You can also use variables, like `http://localhost:#{HTTP_PORT}`, where `HTTP_PORT=8080` is defined earlier in the Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 8):

Vagrant doesn't need a plugin to display a message at the end, just add a shell provisioner after all your other provisioners and have that echo whatever you want.

```ruby
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
  # ... or other existing provisioners

config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-EOF
  echo "Vagrant Box provisioned!"
  echo "Local server address is http://#{$hostname}"
EOF
```

With that, `vagrant up` should end with something like this:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Vagrant Box provisioned!
==> default: Local server address is http://vagrant.dev
```

Adding `privileged: false` (as mentioned in Vagrant [Issue 1673](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1673)) is necessary to suppress Ubuntu's `stdin: is not a tty` error.

Comment: Note that if you want to use a Ruby variable in the args, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17745840/5240327) has you covered.

Comment: What if you have a Vagrantfile that brings up multiple VM's? I don't want the up message to show up several times. i =really= want it to show up after all the processing is done and before vagrant exits.

Comment: This still works but should be considered obsolete in favor of `config.vm.post_up_message` as mentioned in Cory Klein's answer from 2016-04-26

Answer (score 5):

Try the [vagrant-triggers plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers):

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-triggers
```

Then add:

```
config.trigger.after :up do
  puts 'hello'
end
```

to the `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: This will only execute on the first `vagrant up`, and only thereafter for `vagrant provision`.  Hence, it might not do *quite* what you want.

Comment: Updated answer - came across a different plugin which *might* do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The heredoc solution from @slm is super-cute, but you can also put the heredoc *in* the Ruby thus:

```
config.vm.post_up_message = <<-HEREDOC
  This is line 1
  This is line 2
  THis is line 3
HEREDOC
```

Actually there are a couple of slightly different Ruby heredoc styles: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/multiline-strings-ruby-2-3-0-the-squiggly-heredoc